# Recording output volume from machine using flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, red5

I successfully created an application where i can record microphone sound using flash and then save that stream to a server called "Red5" .

But lately i came across a strange requirement of capturing the output volume from machine and then saving that stream to red5 server.Like if i listen to a song or a skype call or listening to any other sound.I just want to capture those sounds.

I searched for this sort of situation just to get an headstart but i havent found any solution so that i can proceed with it.

Can anyone here provide a start up solution for this.
Can this be done through flash?Or any other way ?

Any help will be appreciated.Please provide suggestions

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Certainly there are ways to get this done, however using Flash as is I don't see it being possible (most likely a security concern, don't want ads arbitrarily recording peoples conversations).

Programs like Audacity are capable of recording off of the StereoMix output of a computer which is essentially what you're asking about.  You could potentially build an AIR app that includes an ANE that packages the functionality from Audacity, but would require quite a bit of porting and... well time.

Comment: Ok ,thanks for the reply.is it possible to do it as a desktop aplication